# $(-1)^{i+j}$ factor in the cofactor formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Need the explanation of why there is a $(-1)^{i+j}$ factor in the cofactor formula. [image]
I thought that it might be an effect of the row swapping, which in turn affect the determinant sign, but I can't find any confirmation.

Comment: That is because it enters in the Laplace expansion formula.

Comment: You would have more insight if you try a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and write out what are $C_{11}, C_{12}, C_{21}, C_{22}$.

Comment: @Jack I got u but I want to see a formal proof for the cofactor formula

Comment: @cookies12: I am confused: isn't the formula (4) a *definition* of the $(i,j)$-cofactor of $A$? We don't need to "prove" definitions.

Comment: Or what is the definition of "cofactor" in your book?

Comment: (4) is **not** the "cofactor formula" but the *definition* of a cofactor. The cofactor formula is about how one writes $\det(A)$ in terms of the cofactors defined in (4). The proof will very much depend on how one defines $\det(A)$.